# undefined error at calling method in controller from jquery ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I want to call a method from a controller to calculate a basic arithmetic operation. However, I get only undefined error. My code is

```
$("#equals3").click(
    function () {
        let display = $("#calculatorDisplay");
        let currentValue = display.val();
        $.ajax({
            url:'Calculator/EvaluateExpressionAJAX',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { expression: currentValue },
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (response) {

                if (response.success) {
                    alert(response);
                } else {

                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert("error!");
            }
        });
    });
```

My controller contains

```
public static Dictionary<string, ArithmeticOperation> EvaulationDictionary = new Dictionary<string, ArithmeticOperation> {
        { "+", (a, b) => a + b},
        { "-", (a, b) => a - b},
        { "*", (a, b) => a * b},
        { "/", (a, b) => a / b},
        { "%", (a, b) => a % b} };
    [HttpPost]

    public double EvaluateExpressionAJAX(string expression)
    {
        expression = expression.Trim();
        string[] splitExpression = Regex.Split(expression, @"\s+");
        double a = Convert.ToDouble(splitExpression[0]);
        double b = Convert.ToDouble(splitExpression[2]);
        string op = splitExpression[1];
        return EvaulationDictionary[op](a, b);
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What and where are you exactly seeing the error? Can we have a error stack?

Comment: Is this MVC or WebApi?

Comment: You are assuming that `splitExpression` will always end up having 3 elements, check if effectively it does...

Answer (score 0):

If you would put a breakpoint in the javascript you'll probably find that MVC/WebApi returns an error page with a message like:

`Invalid JSON primitive: expression`

The JSON that you post is not valid, it isn't even JSON.

If you would replace that with:

```
data: "{ \"expression\": \"" + currentValue +"\" }",
```

That would post valid json to the ActionMethod.

A better option would be to create a JavaScript Object and stringify that, like this:

```
// create a js object before the Ajax call
let dataObj = { "expression": currentValue };
// change the data you send to this
data: JSON.stringify(dataObj),
```

And secondly: Take a good look at the url, I can't be sure, but if the page you rendered this from is the same controller and the index method, this probably won't work as you would expect. Change the URL to:

```
url:'/Calculator/EvaluateExpressionAJAX',
```

to make it absolute.

And finally, there are lot of possible bugs in the Action method. You can't expect users to supply 3 parts where part 1 and 3 are doubles. So there is a lot of checking missing.

And last but not least, if this is MVC, it is probably best to return `ActionResult` or some subtype, in this case `JsonResult` would suit best, from an actionmethod.